# Update a team photo with Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK

Tags: powershell, graph, sdk

I want to update the photo of team with Microsoft Graph PowerShell Cmdlets.
run  `Connect-MgGraph` successfully, and also `Update-MgTeam`.
but there is a error when I run `Get-MgTeamPhoto`

Error:

> Get-MgTeamPhoto: The term'Get-MgTeamPhoto' is the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Not recognized as before.
> Make sure the name is written correctly, and if it contains a path,
> make sure it is correct Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-MgTeamPhoto` is a part of the "beta" version of the Microsoft Graph SDK API. You have to change your Microsoft Graph profile to the "beta" version before you connect in order to access the beta version of the API:

```
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
```

```
PS C:\> Get-MgProfile

Name Description
---- -----------
v1.0 A snapshot of the Microsoft Graph v1.0 API for the Global cloud.

PS C:\> Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
PS C:\> Get-MgProfile

Name Description
---- -----------
beta A snapshot of the Microsoft Graph beta API for the Global cloud.

PS C:\> Connect-MgGraph
Welcome To Microsoft Graph!
PS C:\> Get-MgTeamPhoto -TeamId 12345678-fa70-419b-1122-7da1246bbda9

Id      Height Width
--      ------ -----
648X648 648    648
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I changed my  profile to the "beta" version,run Get-MgTeamPhoto,not successfully.

Error:
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ TeamId = 1d25...ndProperty =  }:<>f__AnonymousType47`3) [Get-MgTeam
   Photo_Get]、RestException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Forbidden,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetMgTeamPhoto_Get